# Covariance of dependent Poisson-processes.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have a pretty easy-to understand task, but I am struggling to solve it.

We have $X$, which is $\mathrm{Poi}(1)$ **point process.**

We have $X_1$, which happens in the $[0,3]$ interval, and $X_2$, which is on $[2,4]$ interval. They are both **point processes**, with same $\lambda=1$.

Question is $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$.

**My approach:**

Since $X$ is a Poisson-distribution, with $\lambda=1$, $E(X_1)=3, E(X_2)=2$ from Poisson-distribution definiton.

However, $E(X_1 X_2)$ seems to be the tricky one, since they are not independent.

I tried to seperate $X_1$ to $[0,2]+[2,3]$, and $X_2$ to $[2,3]+[3,4]$, but no idea how to move forward.

Any help appreciated

Comment: I edited the question, sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: OK, so you are saying there is a Poisson process, and $X_1$ is the count of events in the time interval $[0,3]$ and $X_2$ is the count of events in the time interval $[2,4]$

Comment: Exactly, that is what I mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it easier to try $Y_1$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $2$, $Y_2$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $1$, $Y_3$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $1$, all independent.  This makes $X_1=Y_1+Y_2$ and $X_2=Y_2+Y_3$

Then you want $\operatorname{Cov}(Y_1+Y_2,Y_2+Y_3)$, which is not difficult to calculate: it is $\operatorname{Var}(Y_2)=1$

Comment: What exactly you mean by $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$? :)

Comment: $Y_1$ is the count in the time interval $[0,2)$, $Y_2$ is the count in the time interval $[2,3]$, and $Y_3$ is the count in the time interval $(3,4]$,

Comment: I see, thanks for your help!